# Where is my angular project picking up the A favicon.ico from? It's not in my project

Tags: angular, angular-material, favicon

Just recently, code that has worked correctly since 2018 has started falsely showing the old default "A" favicon.ico from Angular. I have combed my code and can't find it anywhere. All of my entries point to the correct favicon.ico, which is a brand. This happened last week and I closed my browser and reloaded everything and it went away. Today, I moved from one building to another, switching wi-fi. I changed my start command from a specific IP address, ng serve --host 192.168.40.170, to a more generic ng serve, which is localhost, and it popped back up again!

[image]

I tried rebooting the browser, but this time it didn't go away. Am I the only one seeing this new irritation?

Answer (score 3):

#### You have different solutions to solve this problem:

**1. Replace the default `favicon.ico` by your icon:**

1. Remove the default `src\favicon.ico` from angular
2. Replace the `favicon.ico` with your icon in the `src` folder

**2. Use PNG as default icon (before Angular 9):**

1. Remove the default `src\favicon.ico` from angular
2. Add your icon `favicon.png` in the `src` folder
3. Add it in the `index.html`

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
```

4. Add your `assets` in your angular config file (`angular-cli.json` or `angular.json`)

*angular-cli.json:*

```json
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.png"
],
```

**3. Use PNG\ICO as default icon (after Angular 9):**

1. Remove the default `src\favicon.ico` made by angular
2. Add your icon (`favicon.png` or `favicon.ico`) in the `assets` folder to make it visible to the browser
3. Change file in the `index.html` (`favicon.png` or `favicon.ico`)

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href=".assets/favicon.png">
```

4. Add your assets and you file (`favicon.png` or `favicon.ico`) in your angular config file (`angular-cli.json` or `angular.json`)

*angular.json:*

```json
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.png"
],
```

**5. Completely remove default `favicon.ico` from angular:**

1. Remove from index.html

```json
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

2. Remove "favicon.ico" from assets in the config file (`angular-cli.json` or `angular.json`)
3. Delete src/favicon.ico

**6. Clear your browser (cache, cookies...) :**

*Windows:*

- IE: `Ctrl+R`
- Firefox: `Ctrl+Shift+R`
- Chrome: `Ctrl+R` or `Ctrl+F5` or `Shift+F5`

*Linux:*

- Firefox: `Ctrl+Shift+R`
- Chrome: `Ctrl+R` or `Ctrl+F5` or `Shift+F5`

*macOS:*

- Safari: `⌘+R`
- Firefox/Chrome: `⌘+Shift+R`

Comment: `flavicon`... not enough characters for an edit